# C#: Trigger button click on keypress

Tags: c#

How to trigger a button's click event when the desired key on the keyboard is pressed?
Windows Forms C# .NET Framework on Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [KeyPreview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?view=net-5.0) to `true`, so that the window will receive the keypress events. You can then handle the event on Form level.